# Multiple videos autoplay in FullPage JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, fullpage.js

I have already seen many answers on here and github (well addressed by Alvaro) on enabling video autoplay in FullPage.js

However I am having issues when I have several videos, each on a different slide, that need to autoplay by default. So far with this code I have been able to only auto start the first video:

```
afterRender: function () {
        //playing the video
        $('video').get(0).play();
    }
```

As far as I understand, this function needs to work in conjunction with afterSlideLoad for this to take place, but had no luck. Has anyone had experience with autoplaying several videos on different slides/pages?

Comment: Did you try to check with simple console.log('afterRender trigger'); if afterRender event is triggered?

Comment: Or did you check for any `console errors`?

Comment: afterRender is definitely triggered but it only affects the first video. No errors in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple videos you would need to loop through them to play them.
Assumming you use jQuery in your page, this should do the trick:

```
afterRender: function () {
    $('video').each(function () {
        //playing the video
        $(this).get(0).play();
    });
}
```

If you want to play each of them disparately only when the slide loads, then you would need to use `afterSlideLoad` as you mention and probably assign an `id` tag to the video so you can play each of them whenever you want, for example:

```
<video autoplay loop muted controls="false" id="video1">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Notice the `id="video1"` in the video element. 
And now in the jQuery code:

```
afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    //for section 2 slide 2
    if (index == 2 && slideIndex == 2) {

        //playing #video1
        $('#video1').each(function () {
            //playing the video
            $('video').get(0).play();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A very elaborate answer, hugely appreciated Alvaro. In this instance the first example you gave works perfectly, all videos preload and autoplay. I hope someone else will find this answer as useful as I have. Thank you.